# Reading the doc file with the use of Apache POI & docx4j

Tags: java, android, apache-poi, .doc

Reading the doc file with the use of Apache POI & docx4j.

i had read the doc file with the use of docx4j & even with Apache POI but the problem is when i extract the data from it it only return **TEXT** not **Images**. & even i didn't any notation of new paragraph started or paragraph ended..

is there any solution for that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have read your problem is that the returned data from the doc is only text (string type) this is because data inputted in bitmaps is also an array of chars.

you might want to use a parser wich recognizes the character sequence and renders it to bitmap extensions.

Comment: Java has several method when it comes to file reading one of them being imageIO here is a sample:http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.imageio/BasicImageRead.html